# MongoDB - Insert 2 documents, each in another collection but share ObjectId

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, insert, id-generation

I have this question:
I want to insert 2 documents into 2 collections.

One is for user and one is for company.

Both inserts are requested via api.

In created(Inserted) company I want to know, which user[Created/inserted] create this company. And in user i want to have _id of company that he inserted.

User
{
_id: "userGeneratedId",
companyId : Company._id
}

Company
{
_id: "companyGeneratedId",
registeredByID : user._id
}

How can this be done?

Thank you,
Dufino

Comment: We need  your db structure

Comment: Are you also inserting user details?

Comment: Yes, I am inserting company data to company collection and user data to user collection. I want to share IDs between them. Like I wrote in question - User is one collection and Company is another Collection.

Comment: Well, your question lacks adequate information to help solve your issue

Comment: Sorry, I that was not clear. I am inserting 2 separate data - for User like name, email,..
For Company I insert data like - company name, residence,...
Each of these data get on insertion their own _id, but I want to connect them via other ids.
How can I get that id on insertion when both are inserting on same time? Is there way to do it simply or I have to create one, create second with connected id of first then update first with second id?

Comment: Now I get your point. gimme a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this

**The first and easy way**

Add new fields to your user and company model. maybe call it `userSaveId` or whatever you choose. Now you will insert same unique id to these new fields fields, so that when you are retrieving a company, you can just retrieve it based on that ID.

---

The second way this could be done is by performing 4 operations. 2 insert operations and two update operations. Note that this would slightly increase the response time of your operations.

Suppose you have inserted a `user` and `company`, get the `IDs` of both the `user document` and `company document` as such:

```
const user = User.save(yourData);
const company = Company.save(yourCompanyData);
```

Afterwards get the ids and use it to update the documents that are already stored as such:

```
const userId = user._id;
const companyId = company._id;

User.updateOne({_id: userId}, {$set: {companyId: companyId}});
Company.updateOne({_id: companyId}, {$set: {registeredByID: userId}});
```

So the complete code would be this:

```
const user = User.save(yourData);
const company = Company.save(yourCompanyData);
const userId = user._id;
const companyId = company._id;

User.updateOne({_id: userId}, {$set: {companyId: companyId}});
Company.updateOne({_id: companyId}, {$set: {registeredByID: userId}});
```

Comment: I get it! Thank you! :) I will implement that tommorow.